# How do you earn Loot Boxes?

Tags: overwatch

I've been earning Loot Boxes by leveling up. But I believe player level caps out at 40. Is there any way to earn Loot Boxes after hitting 40 or do you just not get them and have to pay money for the rest of the cosmetics?

Comment: Even if there was a level cap, the achievements for leveling go up to 50, so it would have to be higher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There is no level cap](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4557kp/xp_gain_and_player_levels_breakdown/). You continue to earn loot boxes roughly every 22,000 XP.

Comment: Although there is no level cap, the displayed level only goes up to 100. After that, it resets to Level 1 and you get a different colored border displayed around your hero icon.
http://www.overpwn.com/news/152-tracers-over-the-shoulder-pose-removal-drama-all
You can essentially determine a player's actual level by the displayed level number and their border color.

Comment: Will the 1 box for each level be keept in release?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264491/will-there-be-a-reset-after-open-beta